# Почему выводит аргументы в bash-скрипте, вместо того чтобы их реализовать?

Tags: linux

Вот простенький скрипт для вывода характеристик процессора:

```
#!bin/bash
echo "Процессор"
echo -en "\t Модель - " & lscpu | grep 'Модель' | awk '{print $2}'
echo -en "\t Архитектура - " & lscpu | grep 'Архитектура' | awk '{print $2}'
echo -en "\t Тактовая частота - " & lscpu | grep 'CPU max MHz' | awk '{print $3, $4}'
echo -en "\t Количество ядер - " & lscpu | grep 'Ядер на сокет' | awk '{print $4}'
```

Почему выводит в консоль -en вместо того, чтобы выполнять его? Если вводить страну в терминале то все работает как нужно. Работает как нужно и на онлайн лиуксовых машинах. Как можно исправить?

Comment: о какой стране речь?

Comment: `&` - отвязывает от сессии процесс, если вы хотите в случае успеха выполнить следующую команду, то следует использовать `&&`, так же вы просто можете пометить команду `lscpu` внутри `echo` сделав `echo "text - $(command)"`

Comment: У вас неправильный shebang и видимо скрипт таки выполняется дефолтным шеллом в котором у echo нет таких параметров

Comment: Может лучше так? https://superuser.com/a/1670367/505198

Answer (score 1):

Уже ответил Alexey Ten, что у Вас неправильный shebang. На самом деле надо написать вот так:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Запустив скрипт после исправления, получаем:

```
./test.sh
Процессор
     Модель - 94
     Архитектура - x86_64
     Тактовая частота - MHz: 4000,0000
     Количество ядер - 4
```